# Laravel detect API call origin

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to detect if the API call is being made outside my website or not. This is due to several factors, such as:

1. Apply throttle restrictions according to subscription plans but only for calls outside
2. Save parameters into database if requests being made by outside
3. Apply API endpoint restrictions based if outside or not

Example:

```
www.mywebsite.com/api/v1/customers
```

- Access: inside & outside
- Throttle inside: none
- Throttle outside: 1000 requests per hour (Plan A)
- Throttle outside: 2500 requests per hour (Plan B)
- Save request into database if outside

Example 2

```
www.mywebsite.com/api/v1/subscription/plan
```

- Access: inside
- Throttle inside: none
- Throttle outside: none
- Throttle outside: none
- Doesn't save request

Can I accomplish this with a middleware & headers detection? Or will I have to create certain API tokens that will tell me that is a outside or inside request?

For example, with a middleware I am unable to get the `sec-fetch-site` header parameter, because it's always null.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class HasAccess
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Always returns null
        if ($request->header('sec-fetch-site') != 'same-origin')
            return false;
    
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the Laravel version?

Comment: @Milk version 7.

Comment: What are you using to test? I tested with Chrome and what you did is right. Not all browsers have full support for this header yet

Comment: Well I used the Postman, people will be using all sort of things, desktop apps, websites, etc

Comment: @Milk i think i'm gonna solve it with different tokens / roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**.

Applied different role to the API User and now I'm able to customize my middlewares.

```
class HasAccess
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (\Auth::user()->role == 'API')
            abort(404);
    
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```